# How does the hodge codifferential operator act over a wedge product?

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, hodge-theory

We have that the exterior derivative acts over a wedge product in the following manner. Let $\alpha,\beta$ be $p,q$ forms respectively. Then we have that 
\begin{equation}
d(\alpha\wedge \beta) = (d\alpha)\wedge\beta+ (-1)^p \alpha\wedge(d\beta)
\end{equation}

Is it then true, by the fact that the hodge codifferential $\delta$ is the adjoint operator to $d$, that it acts in the same way, considering it has hidden inside the exterior derivative itself? For example, 
\begin{equation}
\delta(\alpha \wedge\beta)=(\delta\alpha)\wedge\beta + (-1)^p\alpha \wedge (\delta\beta)
\end{equation}
Should this be obvious? Thanks!

Edit: Attempt

I tried to derive the relation and this is as far as I got in a coordinate basis:
Let $\alpha = \frac{1}{p!}\alpha_{a_1\ldots a_p}f^{a_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge f^{a_p}, \, \beta = \frac{1}{q!}\beta_{b_1\ldots b_q}f^{b_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge f^{b_q}$, then one can show that

$$\star d \star (\alpha \wedge \beta)=\frac{(-1)^{n(p+q-1)}s}{p!q!}\nabla_b \alpha^{[b a_2\ldots a_p}\beta^{a_{p+1}\ldots a_{p+q}]}f_{a_{2}}\wedge\ldots\wedge f_{a_{p+q}}
$$
Where $s$ is the signature of the metric, $f^a \equiv dx^a$ are the coordinate $1$-forms, and $\nabla$ is the (at least Koszul, but could be Levi-Civita) connection on the manifold.

Is there a way someone can see to simplify this? Thanks again!

Edit: So, by staring at it, I believe you can convince yourself that we can apply Leibniz rule to the $\alpha\beta$ term, yielding

$$\star d \star (\alpha \wedge \beta)=\frac{(-1)^{n(p+q-1)}s}{p!q!}
\left[ (\nabla_b \alpha^{[b a_2\ldots a_p})\beta^{a_{p+1}\ldots a_{p+q}]} + \alpha^{[b a_2\ldots a_p}(\nabla_b\beta^{a_{p+1}\ldots a_{p+q}]}) \right] f_{a_{2}}\wedge\ldots\wedge f_{a_{p+q}}
$$

Then we have that, in coordinates, the codifferential acting on a $p$ form is $\delta = (-1)^{n(p-1)+1}s \star d \star$ and in coordinates, its action on $\alpha$ would be

$$\delta\alpha = \frac{1}{(p-1)!}\left[-\nabla^b \alpha_{b a_2 \ldots a_p}\right]f^{a_2}\wedge\ldots\wedge f^{a_p}
$$

I think I'm onto something...

Comment: Nothing *should* be obvious. The fact that you are asking is proof eenough that it is not obvious.

Comment: Sure, just in case someone knows of a theorem I don't and says "it is easy to see that"... Just ruling it out. Guess I'll just derive it.

Comment: Neither the Hodge star nor $d^*$ have any nice algebraic formulas w/r/t the wedge product (as far as I know, at least), though you can of course calculate what they are in coordinates, and there should be global formulas for them involving $d$, $\wedge$, and a contraction operator for forms of different degree (which you have on a Riemannian manifold).

Comment: Your question has been solved by Mike Miller in [chat], cf. [conversation starting here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40417924#40417924).

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something; nowhere have I mentioned that $\alpha,\beta$ are harmonic? In fact if you were to act $\Delta = d\delta + \delta d$ on either form, you do not necessarily get 0, a term that goes like $d\delta d$ survives: so that surely is not the case?

Comment: @MKF If $M$ is a compact manifold, a form is harmonic if and only if both $d\alpha$ and $d^*\alpha$ are zero. If $\alpha, \beta$ are then harmonic on a compact manifold, and something like your second formula was true, $\alpha \wedge \beta$ would also be coclosed and hence harmonic. This is false in most examples.

Comment: Of course this is just me being lazy and invoking big theory so that I don't actually have to do any calculations. I suspect if you wrote down some nice forms on eg the upper half plane model for $\Bbb H^2$ and calculated $d^*$ you would see that this doesn't work. (The fact that you can run my argument on $\Sigma_g$, $g > 1$, with a hyperbolic metric, shows that there exist a great many such examples.)

Comment: I should have said, I am considering this on a non compact pseudoriemannian manifold to begin with. Assume also that $d \alpha \neq 0$, which we can do (since $d(\alpha_{a_1\ldots a_p}) = \partial_c \alpha_{a_1\ldots a_p}f^c$, $\alpha_{a_1\ldots a_p}$ being a function of the coordinates of course). At the same time, the codifferential is not necessarily zero (that would be boring in this case).

Comment: That's fine, it's almost midnight for me too, I am feeling the laziness settle in :)

Comment: Your formula doesn't work in the simplest cases; I see no reason to believe that making the situation more complicated will help. Explicit computation on some interestingly curved spaces will probably still show this, but I don't know any pseudoriemannian geometry and have none to suggest.